# Stop Notifications when the App is closed

Tags: applications, notifications, outlook, background-process

This may be a stupid question since the Android is maybe supposed to work this way, still though I am wondering if this is possible.

Two apps, Microsoft Teams and Outlook are sending the notifications when the app is "closed". Now i would like for that NOT to happen when the app is closed. Is there any way whatsoever, that i can stop the notifications when the app is "closed"? I understand that the app is probably always running in the background and that until force stop it is never really closed. I am just wondering if I am missing something that can be chosen in the notifications settings that i havent found yet.

Also, i do realise that you can choose the "quiet hours" in the App settings itself, but that is not something i am looking for.

Comment: Push messages by design can wake-up (or even start) the app they belong to. The only chance to silence them is the "Do Not Disturb Mode" or if the app supports a different processing of push messages during certain hours.

Comment: Hello Robert, i was afraid you might say that but thank you for clearing it up for me!

Comment: You can block notifications of specific apps with Automate app. Tell me if you are okay with using a 3rd party app

Comment: @velvethadron If you want an app to **not show** any notification at all, you can long press the app -> go to app info. -> notifications -> and deny permission

Answer (score 0):

So far I've found three ways to prevent notifications:

1. Remove the app. -- definitely not useful 99.9% of the time

   1. Or, as you found out, kill any process that app. is running
2. The app. itself has some settings, including whether to send notifications or not
3. In the global Settings, go to Applications, search for the App, check the Notifications there and turn off what you do not want to be notified about

(1) is not likely what you want, (2) is rarely implemented and (3) is usually rather limited... so in many cases, it won't help you much. That being said, (3) can be an app. savior.

As Robert mentioned in a comment, the Android OS works by automatically waking up / starting applications when they receive messages if they were not running at that point. When installing an app., it can register the events it is interested in and it will receive them *no matter what* (nearly). And notifications work that way too...

In the cases you mentioned, it may require a `poll()` by the app. In that case, the app. has to be running. In generally, a very small amount of the app. gets loaded, just enough to handle the necessary code to run the polling. If the app. doesn't offer an option to turn that polling off, then it just won't go away without uninstalling.